# Can't access any web service in ios from app store

Tags: ios, web-services, nsurlconnection

I used NSURLConnect in my app to start web service connection. I knew that apple deprecated this interface since ios 9.0 for more safty, while it also said a way to support http(add some para in xcode config to forbid ATS). I exactly did as it said, and it run well when I developed(use usb connect to ipad which run in ios 9).

My app was designed for inner net envirenment. I uploaded a vedio for detail introduce when I submit it to apple, because they certainly could not connect to my server. Nicely they approved my app.

Now I'm very glad to say my app is ready for sale. But when I setup it from app store and run, strange thing happens, it can not connect to the server! Through log I see the reason is no byte send succeefully by NSURLConnect sendSynchronousRequest. Why it runs well by devoloping, I am sure the code I submit is the same, and the ipad is run as ios 9.

I guess maybe I do something wrong during uploading. There is some info of my develop envirenment:

1. Xcode 7.2
2. Deployment Target 8.0
3. Base SDK ios 9.2(Latest)
4. Build Active Architecture Only
   Debug Yes
   Release No

   I use xcode Archive to upload. BTW, I have tested in ipad runs in ios 8.2 it was also not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 9.0 Apple made ssl a requirement but in the meantime provided a workaround.

Make sure your `Info.plist` file has NSAppTransportSecurity added to it.
This example will allow you to make any connection.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I have done as you said and it runs well, while after submit to apple store it is wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't show the error instead of other custom words. I located in the code it showed the interface sendSynchronousRequest was returned at once. Yes, it was always returned immediately whatever ip address.

Comment: I find the reason! The Optimization Levle! In release it's default fast and smallest, and none in debug. I usually run in debug module while submit in release. Just now I try run in release and I receive the same error msg. I modify opt level as none, and run well!